# SQL Server Management Studio -- Script that executes other scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So I have been looking around for a way to develop a script that will execute other scripts from within my project folder using SQL Server Management Studio and so far none of the other solutions have worked.  I tried writing a script that had the sqlcommandline stuff in it:

```
sqlcmd -S.\SQLExpress -imyScript.sql;
```

and that didn't work and from my understanding using `@\path\to\script.sql` won't work either so any other ideas?  Or should I start looking into writing a procedure?  In which case, could anybody point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd look into writing stored procedures.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) is good and there are lots of resources on line if you do a quick search.

Alternatively you could do something like this to MAKE it happen (you'll need to have permission to execute command shell, etc):

```
CREATE TABLE ##SQLFiles ( SQLFileName VARCHAR(2000))
GO

INSERT INTO ##SQLFiles
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir /b "C:\SQL Scripts\*.sql"'
GO

DECLARE cFiles CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT [SQLFileName]
    FROM ##SQLFiles
    WHERE [SQLFileName] IS NOT NULL AND
          [SQLFileName] != 'NULL'
    ORDER BY [SQLFileName]

DECLARE @vFileName            VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @vSQLStmt             VARCHAR(4000)

OPEN cFiles
FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @vFileName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- The following SET command must be on a single line or else an error will be generated.
    -- It is split in this script for readability purposes.
    SET @vSQLStmt = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''osql -S Server Name -U User Name -P Password
                     -d Database Name -i "C:\SQL Scripts\' + @vFileName + '"'''
    EXECUTE (@vSQLStmt)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @vFileName
END

CLOSE cFiles
DEALLOCATE cFiles
GO

DROP TABLE ##SQLFiles
GO
```

Comment: Well thank you, I think I'll look into developing a procedure then but I do appreciate all of your assistance.